# How to do checkAll options for angular2 dropdown multiselect

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular6

I am using this library for multiselect options ,i have checkbox overthere, need to select all the checkbox while user click select all check box ,how to do this,any one have  implemented before.
https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Comment: this is not an answer to your question, but i suggest you to check this library https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown i have been using many os the components that they exposed and i think they are really easy to implement and configure.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtupvx)

Settings:

```
 mySettings: IMultiSelectSettings = {
     enableSearch: false,
     showCheckAll: true,
     showUncheckAll: true,
     checkedStyle: 'checkboxes',
     autoUnselect: true,
     containerClasses: 'displayBlock',
     dynamicTitleMaxItems: 3,
     displayAllSelectedText: true
  };
```

Display Text:

```
myTexts: IMultiSelectTexts = {
    checkAll: 'Select all',
    uncheckAll: 'Unselect all',
}
```

HTML:

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" [options]="myOptions" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```